# OneLogin's SCIM Provisioning for user App Configuration

Tags: onelogin

Getting error : "fname lname could not be provisioned in SCIM Provisioner with SAML (Core Schema v1.1): Expected SCIM attribute '' to be an object" while configuring onelogin's SCIM app. I am able to see user info in response but still getting this error. Also where would I get SCIM Bearer Token?

Answer (score 0):

Bearer token should come from the application you're trying to integrate with and that error usually comes from something in the return payload not being properly formatted or a required SCIM field (like id) not being returned at all.

I'd recommend contacting [OneLogin developer support](https://onelogin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) as these sorts of issues are a bit too complex to debug via Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your help. Let me check. Yes, I have sent a support request. Waiting for a reply.